# Drawing a Conformal Line

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know how to draw the dashed line as a precise conformal line along the green circles.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Use the Pen tool.. draw a path.. tick the "dashed" option on the Stroke Panel.

Answer (score 3):

- Select all the circles
- **Copy** > **Paste in Front** <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Fill color = none
- Stroke = 100% black, aligned outside and the same size as the separation from the green circles
- **Menu Object** > **Expand**
- **Pathfinder** > **Unite**
- **Menu Object** > **Compound Shape**  > **Release**
- **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Delete the inner shapes and keep the exterior shape
- Fill color = none
- Set the stroke width and type dashed
- **Menu Effect** > **Stylize**  > **Round corners**

[image: circles]

Comment: Hi Danielillo, thanks so much, I am still having trouble with this, do you happen to offer any sort of consulting service where I could pay to have you do this for me? Thank you so much!